Google Sign In using Amplify

I am integrating Google Sign In with Amplify but I cannot get rid of the full redirect url in the Auth Screen. It looks ugly and I wouldn't care if it says just amazoncognito.com
It's for a flutter application, any advice?? I've been checking some tutorials and in all of them just appears amazoncognito.com
I follow these steps:

Configure OAuth Consent Screen
OAuth 2.0 Client IDs Credentials
Copy ClientID and secret one to Amplify
Copy redirect URL from Amplify to OAuth 2.0 Client IDs Credentials

Thanks for helping
